# How do I send a message to all client threads in my TCP IP server in Python?

Tags: python, tcp, server, ip, client

I'm trying to build a TCP IP server in Python.
My goal is to run commands on the clients.
To run a command you'll have to type "cmd command" in the server.
I've never worked with threads before and now I can't seem to find out how to send the command I want to execute to the client threads.
Could anyone point me in the right direction?

My code so far:

```
    import socket
    import sys
    from thread import *

    HOST = ''
    PORT = 8884
    clients = 0
    connected_id = ""

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print 'Socket created'

    # Bind socket to local host and port
    try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error, msg:
        print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
        sys.exit()

    print 'Socket successfully binded'

    # Start listening on socket
    s.listen(10)
    print 'Socket is listening'


    # Function for handling connections.
    def clientthread(conn):
        # Sending message to connected client
        conn.sendall('hello')  # send only takes string
        global clients
        # loop until disconnect
        while True:
            # Receiving from client
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if data.lower().find("id=-1") != -1:
                clients += 1
                print("new client ID set to " + str(clients))
                conn.sendall("SID=" + str(clients))
            if not data:
                break

        # If client disconnects
        conn.close()

    def addclientsthread(sock):
        # start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print('Client connected on ' + addr[0])
        start_new_thread(clientthread, (conn,))

    def sendallclients(message):

        # send msg to all clients
        tmp = 0

    # now keep talking with the clients
    start_new_thread(addclientsthread, (s,))
    usr_input = ""
    while str(usr_input) != "Q":
        # do stuff
        usr_input = raw_input("Enter 'Q' to quit")
        if usr_input.find("cmd") == 0:
            sendallclients(usr_input[3:])
        if usr_input.find("hi") == 0:
            sendallclients("hey")
    s.close()
```

Comment: Where is `start_new_thread` defined ?

Comment: @t.m.adam it's from thread

Comment: My bad , i thought it was your function . Anyway , as @Newyork167 said , make a `clients` list and add new clients to that . Then you can iterate over that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make a clients list :

```
my_clients = []
```

Then you could modify `addclientsthread` to add new clients to the list :

```
def addclientsthread(sock): 
    global my_clients
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    my_clients += [conn]
    print('Client connected on ' + addr[0])
    start_new_thread(clientthread, (conn,))
```

Next iterate over `my_clients` in the `sendallclients` function :

```
def sendallclients(message): 
    for client in my_clients : 
        client.send(message)
```

Now all clients should receive the `message`

Comment: Did this myself after the solution by @newyork167 thanks for writing it out though. You did it a bit cleaner so I'm going to use your way. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Keep a list of client sockets and loop over the list to send each one the command:

```
cons = [con1, con2, ...]
...
for con in cons:
    con.send(YOUR_MESSAGE)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly this way! Not sure how I couldn't figure this out myself but I'm really happy with you help!